# Using VBScript to send an email with a clickable link

Tags: email, vbscript

I have a web form which sends an email.  The email portion is taken care of by .asp with the following VBScript inside (edited of course)...

```
mail.Subject = "Phone shipped per " & Uploader.Form("Ticket") & " for " & Uploader.Form("Rep")

Mail.HTMLBody = "Team," & Uploader.Form("Rep1st") & "'s phone is being shipped out on UPS: " & Uploader.Form("Tracking") & " and should arrive by " & Uploader.Form("Arrive") & ". This is already provisioned to our Mobile Device Management server." &_
"Your cellphone number is: " & Uploader.Form("Phone") &_

"DUO Mobile Setup:" &_
<br>"Please use the (Security Team) attachment to request an activation link pushed to your phone. Open the attachment, fill in the info and send the message.<b>*</b>  The activation link will come in as a text message. When received, tap the link. If prompted how to open: Select DUO > Always.<b>*</b>  When prompted to Name the account, tap: Next, Save, Skip, Continue & OK." &_

"Mail:" &_
<br>"Please follow the {Outlook Setup} pdf to provision the phone with email." &_
```

---

This outbuts the following in an email

---

> Phone shipped per 222222 for Test Two
>
> Team,
>
> Test's phone is being shipped out on UPS: 123456789 and should arrive
> by 09-16-22. This is already provisioned to our Mobile Device
> Management server.
>
> Your cellphone number is: 1112223333
>
> DUO Mobile Setup:
>
> - Please use the (Security Team} attachment to request an activation link pushed to your phone. Open the attachment, fill in the info and
>   send the message.
> - The activation link will come in as a text message. When received, tap the link. If prompted how to open: Select DUO > Always.
> - When prompted to Name the account, tap: Next, Save, Skip, Continue & OK.
>
> Mail:
>
> - Please follow the {Outlook Setup} pdf to provision the phone with email.

---

What I would like to do is put a clickable link in the "DUO Mobile Setup" which will use the following code...

```
<a href="mailto:email_address_goes_here?subject=Security%20Team%20-%20repush%20Duo%20registration%20to%20new%20phone&body=Hello%20Security%20Team,%0aPlease%20repush%20Duo%20Registration%20to%20my%20new%20phone%20(Activation%20link%20only).%20Details%20below:%20%0a%0aFull%20Name:%20%0aPhone%20Number:%20%0aDevice%20Type:%20Android">Click Here</a>
```

With the result in the email to be...

DUO Mobile Setup:

- Please (Click Here) to request an activation link blah, blah, blah

Answer (score 0):

So, of course right after I post the question, I figure out the answer.  It was the "" surrounding the href info that was messing me up, I needed to use '' instead...

Here is the line:

```
"<br><b>*</b> Please click (<a href='mailto:Your_Email_Here?subject=Security%20Team%20-%20repush%20Duo%20registration%20to%20new%20phone&body=Hello%20Security%20Team,%0aPlease%20repush%20Duo%20Registration%20to%20my%20new%20phone%20(Activation%20link%20only).%20Details%20below:%20%0a%0aName:%20%0aPhone%20Number:%20%0aDevice%20Type:%20Android'>Security Team</a>) to request an activation link pushed to your phone." &_
```

Which results the line in the email as:

DUO Mobile Setup:

- Please click (Security Team) to request an activation link pushed to your phone.